# Why doesn't the _issi.cfg file work in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, issi

I wrote this code to add the splash screen before my installer starts:

```
[ISSI]

#define ISSI_Splash "C:\ABoffice\Install\InnoSetupProject\Images\client.bmp"
#define ISSI_Splash_T 5
#define ISSI_Splash_X 500
#define ISSI_Splash_Y 220
//#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"

[Setup]
AppName=Client AB OFFICE 
AppVersion=5.0
DefaultDirName={sd}\AB_Office\Client
```

The instruction manual says that I can configure my ISSI installation by setting some presets in the "_issi.cfg" file located in the ISSI folder.
Here's how my "_issi.cfg" file looks like:

```
[ISSI Configuration]
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
;#define ISSI_Constants "YYMDHMS"
;#define ISSI_ConstantsSeperator "."
;#define ISSI_Compression
;#define ISSI_BeveledLabel

[Setup]
OutputDir=C:\Inno Setup Output
```

But when I compile my script I get this error:

> [ISPP] Undeclared identifier: "ISSI_IncludePath".

[image]

What do I need to add to my code to be able to read from the `_issi.cfg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `ISSI_IncludePath` in the `_issi.cfg`.

And you then try to include the `_issi.cfg` into your .iss script by referring to it using the `ISSI_IncludePath`.

That's a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).

---

Maybe you wanted to set the `ISSI_IncludePath` in your iss file:

```
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"

#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"
```

Then you will probably have you remove the `#define ISSI_IncludePath` from the `_issi.cfg`.